# Aux Component vs React Fragment which one is better?

Tags: reactjs

I have completed a course where instructor used ***Aux component*** to get rid of adding extra nodes to the DOM like below:

```
const Aux = props => props.children
export default Aux;
```

React has also a default component ***React.Fragment*** to get rid of adding extra nodes to the DOM.

I know they both are same. Is it right? If yes, which one is better?

If no, What's the difference between them?

Comment: React fragment is literally designed to wrap components without adding extra nodes, no point in using a custom one that does the exact same thing. Just use the native fragment component.

Comment: Aux exists from a time before Fragments. With Fragments you no longer need Aux

Comment: Thanks @Jayce444 for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 4):

They are basically the same. I use <> </> which is React.Fragment but even simpler, I believe it came out for last and looks better in my opinion.